# "Unfortunately the application (name) has stopped" message

Tags: android, android-logcat

Whenever I run this app (Explore ca)  I am getting this message "Unfortunately Explore Ca has stopped".
this app displays a list of tours  and gives you the option to filter it by clicking on the menu bar (fancy/cheap/all)

I found the solution:

first step: 
right click on the project -> java -> built path ->source ->add folder -> click gen and src
->click ok

second step:
right click on the project -> go to properties -> libraries -> add jars ->
and then add the jars of your project from the libs folder

MainActivity:

```
package com.exploreca.tourfinder;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.exploreca.tourfinder.db.ToursDataSource;
import com.exploreca.tourfinder.model.Tour;
import com.exploreca.tourfinder.xml.ToursPullParser;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static final String LOGTAG="EXPLORECA";
    public static final String USERNAME="pref_username";
    public static final String VIEWIMAGE="pref_viewimages";

    private SharedPreferences settings;
    private OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;
    private List<Tour> tours;

    ToursDataSource datasource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        listener = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                    String key) {
                MainActivity.this.refreshDisplay();
            }
        };
        settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

        datasource = new ToursDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        tours = datasource.findAll();
        if (tours.size() == 0) {
            createData();
            tours = datasource.findAll();
        }

        refreshDisplay();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_all:
            tours = datasource.findAll();
            refreshDisplay();
            break;

        case R.id.menu_cheap:
            tours = datasource.findFiltered("price <= 300", "price ASC");
            refreshDisplay();
            break;

        case R.id.menu_fancy:
            tours = datasource.findFiltered("price >= 1000", "price DESC");
            refreshDisplay();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void setPreference(View v) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Clicked set");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void refreshDisplay() {
        ArrayAdapter<Tour> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tour>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tours);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        datasource.open();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        datasource.close();
    }

    private void createData() {
        ToursPullParser parser = new ToursPullParser();
        List<Tour> tours = parser.parseXML(this);

        for (Tour tour : tours) {
            datasource.create(tour);
        }

    }
}
```

**LogCat:**

```
06-04 08:39:51.231: D/AndroidRuntime(26469): Shutting down VM
 06-04 08:39:51.231: W/dalvikvm(26469): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught     exception (group=0x40ff4930)
 06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity    ComponentInfo{com.exploreca.tourfinder/com.exploreca.tourfinder.MainActivity}:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.exploreca.tourfinder.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.exploreca.tourfinder-1.apk
 06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2172)
 06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
 06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
 06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
 06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
 06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
  06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
  06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.exploreca.tourfinder.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.exploreca.tourfinder-1.apk
  06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
  06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
  06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
  06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
  06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2163)
  06-04 08:39:51.231: E/AndroidRuntime(26469):  ... 11 more
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.exploreca.tourfinder"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_exploreca"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.exploreca.tourfinder.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It says Didn't find class "com.exploreca.tourfinder.MainActivity",did you define mainactivity in manifest file?

Comment: There will be first package line in `MainActivity` file. Please post it as well.

Comment: Once clean your project and try...

Comment: @Kedarnath it was there but not visible because of formatting, now it should be available

Comment: cleaned that.. still getting the same mistake

Comment: Its class not found exception @Shiran, if cleaned project not worked then, can you please tell me , are you using any third party library in your project???

Comment: inside the manifest.xml try `android:name=".MainActivity"` instead of `android:name="com.exploreca.tourfinder.MainActivity"`

Comment: with the dot?..or without?

Comment: @Shiran try it with the dot.

Comment: @Shiran of course with `.` dot and after doing that, just clean your project. This should solve your problem.

Comment: nothing changed... still getting the mistake

Comment: @Shiran can you please send your code to me?

Comment: how can I send you the code?

Comment: @shiran ok then send it to me, let me check it out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55039/discussion-between-pratik-and-shiran).